# How can i check a validate token jwt

Tags: java, spring, jwt, token

I want to check the validity of a jwt token via rest api call, is there a possibility to do this? (java if possible, because i have a Back-End on Java with spring boot and Front-End on JavaScript with ReactJs)
I have already made token generation with java, with antoher service that use the toeken jwt.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this using `jsonwebtoken` library. You should have jwt secret key that is used to encrypt the jwt token.
You can use these methods in your rest api:

```
public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
  try {
    Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key()).build().parse(authToken);
    return true;
  } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
    logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
  }
  return false;
}

private Key key() {
    return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64.decode(jwtSecret));
}
```

The following dependencies are needed as well:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean validateToken(String authToken) throws IOException {
    try {
        Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
        return true;
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
        log.warn(Expired_JWT_TOKEN);
    } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
        log.warn(INVALID_JWT_TOKEN);
    } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
        log.warn(INVALID_JWT_TOKEN);
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
        log.warn(INVALID_JWT_TOKEN);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        log.warn("Token validation error {}", e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).